# Why can we arbitrarily decide that S(x) = (F(x))^2

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, optimization

I have been doing differential calculus on Khan Academy for some time. Sometimes when Mr Khan decides to avoid the chain rule (because there is a sqaure root in the function), instead of working with square roots, he decides that S(x) (which is our function for this question) is equal to (F(x))^2 which effectively gets rid of the square root so we can avoid doing the chain rule in order to find our derivatives. (See the link below)

[image: Picture of Equation]

What I dont understand is how this is not changing the original function into a completely different function with different answers.

Thank you so much for your help.

Regards,

Joshua

Comment: See the last sentence, starting with "The trick". Yes, they are different functions, but they are still related.

Comment: The `differential-equations` tag does not fit here. I've removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in the context of max/min problems. What is being used here is that if $f$ is a *nonnegative* function, then maximizing its square is the same as maximizing/minimizing the function. The square root is the principal square root, i.e. the positive one, so here this applies.

The reason for this is that the function 
$$
x\mapsto x^2
$$
is increasing for nonnegative $x$, so it maintains inequalities, namely 
$$
x\geq y\iff x^2\geq y^2
$$
And of course the same holds for the opposite inequality sign.

Since Sal is only human, he would prefer to take the derivative of something without a radical than with.

Comment: The function can be defined on $[-4,4]$ in which case it is not nonnegative however it attains its maximum on $[0,4]$ and there you argument applies.

Answer (score 0):

When you square a function, all positive maxima and negative minima become maxima, while all negative maxima, positive minima and zeroes become minima.

[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if we are dealing with non negative maximums and minimums, the function squared maintains its minimas and maximums at the same x value therefore the relation is the same? This makes a ton of sense, I just had to see this graph. Thank you.

Comment: @Shezmula: yep, the square does a "folding".